# in the pager less, how to center the current line on the screen

Tags: command-line-interface, pager

I am using the pager `less`.

How to center the current line on the screen?

I cannot find such a `centering` command.

Answer (score 0):

After another look at the manpage, I find the `-j` option is exactly what I need.